# Importing netCDF data to pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, import, netcdf

I am trying to convert a netCDF file to csv. I have succeeded to do that. However, as illustrated in the attached image, i have two problems in the exported csv. dataframe. First, i need to split datetime into two separate columns (Only Date, Only time). Second, when i run the code i get the same values for the 3 different variables (par,temp, and evap). Here is the code:

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from netCDF4 import num2date
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os

# Reading netCDF file
data = Dataset(r'G:\trial\Jan.nc', 'r')

# Defining parameters and dimensions 
lat = data.variables['latitude'][:]
long = data.variables['longitude'][:]
time = data.variables['time']
times = num2date(time[:], time.units)
par = data.variables['par'][:]
temp = data.variables['t2m'][:]
evap = data.variables['e'][:]

# Importing netCDF data from a single point 
idku_lat = 31.249464
idku_long = 30.210806
lat_diff = (lat - idku_lat)**2
lon_diff = (long - idku_long)**2
min_lat = lat_diff.argmin()
min_long = lon_diff.argmin()

# Creating a pandas DataFrame and import values from  the netCDF file

df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['par','temp','evap'], index = times)

dt = np.arange(0, data.variables['time'].size)

for time_index in dt:
    df.iloc[time_index]= par[time_index,min_lat,min_long]


# Exporting the file to csv.
df.to_csv('my_data.csv')
```

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbhlF.png)

Comment: Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide expected output and actual output.

Comment: Looks like you liked the answer by Dani56.  If so, you can mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your expected ouput is but if you simply want to convert your dataset into a DataFrame then save it as a csv file, you could do this.

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('G:\trial\Jan.nc')
df = ds.to_dataframe()
df = df.reset_index()

date = df['time'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
time =  df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

df['Date'] = date 
df['time'] = time



df.to_csv('myfile.csv',index=True, header=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly . But, if i need to separate Datetime into two columns (for time and date separately), How can i do that ?

Comment: The answer above should answer your second question. The only way I could think of is to format your existing time dimension into separate Date and Time format before adding it your DataFrame and saving it as a csv file.